# How to know what version of VisualStudio is integrated with vcpkg

Tags: point-cloud-library, vcpkg

I need to use PCL(Point Cloud Library) with PCAP.
I heard that I can use PCL without any modification of configuration after installation of PCL using vcpkg.

But, In the new project in VS2017 and VS2019, IDE cannot find source.

My environment and installation steps are blow.

- Windows10
- VS2017 and VS2019 are installed
- I added below code in triplets file "x64-windows.cmake"
  set(VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET v141)
- I installed packages following below steps, in PowerShell.

  1. .\vcpkg install pcl[pcap]:x64-windows --featurepackages
  2. .\vcpkg integrate install
- VS2017 cannot found PCL source, So I Checked project properties.
  There are not any directory values about pcl.
  And, I entered values.

  - "%VCPKG_ROOT%\installed\x64-windows\lib" and files(*.lib)
  - "%VCPKG_ROOT%\installed\x64-windows\include"
  - "%VCPKG_ROOT%\installed\x64-windows\bin"

  But, PCL is still not working
- I also checked "%VCPKG_ROOT%\installed\x64-windows\lib".

  "boost_atomic-vc140-mt.lib" is in this folder.

  vc140 is for VS2015. Isn`t it?

How to install PCL for VS2017, and integrate with VS2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BlueGo](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BlueGo) has support for PCL (right now only Visual Studio 2015 is supported), but it should be not that hard to modify it to support VS 2017.

[image]